# How to dynamically set drawableTop for Button (android)

Tags: android, button

I have a Button:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCap2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_s9cap2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/menu_btn_s9cap2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I need to adjust `drawableTop` dynamically . How can I do this ?
I know how to adjust background but this does not solve my problem.

```
btnCap2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCap2);
drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_s9cap2);
btnCap2.setBackground(drawable);
btnCap2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 btnCap2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drawable, null, null);
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works fine exactly I was looking for !!

Comment: Nice! Could u please accept the answer to close the issue ?